# Native' has exited with code 2 (0x2)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, image-processing, dll

I am using windows8.1 ,visual studio10 and Opencv.
this is my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv/cvaux.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
```

//Mat data structure usage

```
int Arr[256];
int x;
Mat image, A, B;

image = imread("C:/Users/chandanawin8/Desktop/len.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

for(int a=0; a<255;a++){       

    Arr[a] = 0;         } 
//int Arr[256] = {0}   

  if(!image.data){

    printf("Error: Couldn't open the file.\n");
    return 2;

}

  cvtColor(image, A, CV_RGB2GRAY);    

//creating the histogram by taking a count to an arry

for(int i=0; i<A.rows; i++){        

    for(int j=0; j<A.cols;j++){            

x = A.at<uchar>(i,j);
Arr[x] = Arr[x]+1;

        if(x<103){           

            A.at<uchar>(i,j) = 0;    }

        else if(x<219){

            A.at<uchar>(i,j) = (x-103)*(220-1)/(219-103) + 1;        
  }

        else if(x<242){

            A.at<uchar>(i,j) = (x-219)*(255-220)/(242-219) +219;

        }

        else{

        }

        //pixels from 241 to 255: keep them. if want we can remove it

    }

}



for(int a=0; a<255;a++){   

std::cout<<"Number of  "<<a<<"  Value: "<<Arr[a]<<std::endl;

   }



//creating the font
//cvInitFont(&font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 3,3, 0.0, 5,8);

//display the image
cvNamedWindow("Main Window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Main Window", image);

    cvNamedWindow("Display Window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Display Window", A);

cv::waitKey(0);
  image.release();
A.release();    

return 0;
```

}

after running it getting this error

```
'BreailTest2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
The program '[3044] BreailTest2.exe: Native' has exited with code 2 (0x2).
```

any can you help me to solve this
some few day ago it worked.now it is not working .i am little bit new opencv and visual studio
thanks lot

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your image did not load correct.

If you look at the log it told you that the app exited with code 2.

If you look at your code, only place it exits with a 2 is

```
if(!image.data){

    printf("Error: Couldn't open the file.\n");
    return 2;

}
```

I would therefore check that you entered the correct filepath, and that the image file exists,

Answer (score -1):

problem occurs when use Imread function

```
image = imread("C:/Users/chandanawin8/Desktop/len.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

instead above function use bellow function

```
image = cvLoadImage("C:/Users/chandanawin8/Desktop/easy.JPG",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

Comment: dear, no. bad idea. the old c-api calls should be avoided. if imread does not work, you have a larger linker related problem lurking underneath. check if you mixed debug/release libs or such.

Comment: thanks for reply.when i use it cvloardImage function .it is working..shal u explain little bit u said chek debug / release Libs..i am new to opencV

Comment: if you don't know the answers don't involve with